# Angular 10 - Dynamically load a specific less file conditionally

Tags: angular, webpack, less

I am using Less stylesheet format in my Angular (10.0.11) project.

I am dealing with theming using multiple less files (more than 50 themes) and this file can be identified only after calling some initial APIs, so I can't use that directly in styles.less.

Suppose  **assets/theme1.less** corresponds to **THEME_1** and **assets/theme2.less** corresponds to **THEME_2** and so on.App call the initial APIs and informed UI that THEME_2 is to be used.

Could you please explain a way to load a less file globally dynamically (assets/theme2.less in the above case)?

Comment: Angular has documentation on swapping themes at run time [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#changing-styles-at-run-time). have these approaches not not worked for your current use case?

Comment: Hi @Edward, that is to replace the CSS file. My case I am using LESS files and if i am adding that to document, I have to ass less.js and it will be outside of angualr cli's compilation process.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to address this is compile your theme file in a different project and inject the compiled theme css file after your API calls. Just use single default theme for development purposes.

You can generate each theme file with a different path based on the name of theme you want to access.

Ex: `{static-content-path}/{themename}.min.css`